# HTML - How to generate a random number in an img=src address inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, random

Hi_I’m trying to make a random number appear inside an `img src=` address in a div, so that a random image is generated every time the div is loaded.

I have 10 images and their directory addresses are:

```
"pictures/number1.jpg"
"pictures/number2.jpg"
"pictures/number3.jpg"
................
"pictures/number10.jpg"
```

I’m able select one of these at random with the following Javascript:

```
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1); 
img.src = "pictures/number" +num +".jpg";
```

This generates a random number between 1 and 10 and places it inside the address to locate the image.
This works perfectly when the `img.src` is used inside the Javascript file, but I’m wondering if it’s possible to use this method when `img src=` is part of a HTML page. I’m trying to apply a similar process to the following HTML code:

```
<script>
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1); 
randomimage = "pictures/number" +num +".jpg";
</script>

<div id="JohnDIV" align="center"> <img src=randomimage alt="If you can see this, then the image didn't load properly" class="myclass1" /> </div>
<div id="JackDIV" align="center"> <img src=randomimage alt="If you can see this, then the image didn't load properly" class="myclass1" /> </div>
<div id="JaneDIV" align="center"> <img src=randomimage alt="If you can see this, then the image didn't load properly" class="myclass1 /> </div>
```

This isn't working, it's just showing me the `alt=` message. I'm not sure if I've defined `randomimage` correctly. 
I'm really confused about how to go about doing this the right way, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems you are trying something like a server-side code... like php or asp. Javascript does not work like this.

Comment: You've to iterate through [the elements with the class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) you've given to `img`s within the script, and then set `src` for images in that loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Edit

As to why your code isn't working: You can't apply `randomimage` to the source of the image in plain HTML. You have to do that using Javascript. To do that you have to select the element you want to manipulate and modify the `src` attribute through Javascript.

---

Since you tagged this with jQuery I'll start by using it!

You can use an `.each()` loop on your `myClass1` class to iterate over each image and change the image src for each image with the given class.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/press/vj0uo6p7/)**

```js
$('.myClass1').each(function() {

  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1),
    img = $(this);

  img.attr('src', 'pictures/number' + num + '.jpg');
  img.attr('alt', 'Src: ' + img.attr('src'));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="JohnDiv">
  <img src="" class="myClass1" alt="Not Working!" />
</div>
<div class="JohnDiv">
  <img src="" class="myClass1" alt="Not Working!" />
</div>
<div class="JohnDiv">
  <img src="" class="myClass1" alt="Not Working!" />
</div>
<div class="JohnDiv">
  <img src="" class="myClass1" alt="Not Working!" />
</div>
```

For testing purposes the image's `alt` attribute is set to the `src` of the image.

### Edit

Here is another solution using plain Javascript.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/press/vj0uo6p7/1/)**

```js
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass1');

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
  imgs[i].src = 'pictures/number' + num + '.jpg';
  imgs[i].alt = imgs[i].src;
}
```

```html
<div class="JohnDiv">
  <img src="" class="myClass1" alt="Not Working!" />
</div>
<div class="JohnDiv">
  <img src="" class="myClass1" alt="Not Working!" />
</div>
<div class="JohnDiv">
  <img src="" class="myClass1" alt="Not Working!" />
</div>
<div class="JohnDiv">
  <img src="" class="myClass1" alt="Not Working!" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign an id to the img tag

```
<img src="" alt="If you can see this, then the image didn't load properly" class="myclass1" id="sample"/>
```

In your javascript,on the fly you can add an src of your choice

```
<script>
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1); 
randomimage = "pictures/number" +num +".jpg";
document.getElementById('sample').src=randomImage;
</script>
```